# How to make a node.js method wait for another helper method to complete?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a simple api with nodejs which connects to two public apis.

One api is google and the other api is forecast.io.

This module takes in  a zip code and using the google api converts the zip to coordinates that are used by forecast.io to provide simple weather forecast for a given area.

My main problem, is that the program works asynchronously and sometimes the forecast API goes on without waiting for the google api to finish getting the needed data to succeed. How can i prevent the google api call from being skipped? 
Sorry, here is the code:

```
// The required modules.
var http = require("http");
var https = require("https");

//result object
var resultSet = {
    latitude :"",
    longitude:"",
    localInfo:"",
    weather:"",
    humidity:"",
    pressure:"",
    time:""

};

//print out error messages
function printError(error){
    console.error(error.message);
}

//Forecast API required information:
//key for the forecast IO app
var forecast_IO_Key = "<Here goes the key>";
var forecast_IO_Web_Adress = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/";


//Create Forecast request string function
function createForecastRequest(latitude, longitude){
    var request = forecast_IO_Web_Adress + forecast_IO_Key + "/"
                      + latitude +"," + longitude;
    return request;
}

//Google GEO API required information:
//Create Google Geo Request
var google_GEO_Web_Adress =  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";

function createGoogleGeoMapRequest(zipCode){
    var request = google_GEO_Web_Adress+zipCode + "&sensor=false";
    return request;
}

function get(zipCode){
    // 1- Need to request google for geo locations using a given zip
    var googleRequest = https.get(createGoogleGeoMapRequest(zipCode), function(response){
        //console.log(createGoogleGeoMapRequest(zipCode));
        var body = "";
        var status = response.statusCode;
        //a- Read the data.
        response.on("data", function(chunk){
            body+=chunk;
        });
        //b- Parse the data.
        response.on("end", function(){  
            if(status === 200){
               try{
                   var coordinates = JSON.parse(body);
                   resultSet.latitude = coordinates.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                   resultSet.longitude = coordinates.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

                   resultSet.localInfo = coordinates.results[0].address_components[0].long_name + ", " +
                               coordinates.results[0].address_components[1].long_name + ", " +
                               coordinates.results[0].address_components[2].long_name + ", " +
                               coordinates.results[0].address_components[3].long_name + ". ";
               }catch(error){
                   printError(error.message);
               }finally{
                  connectToForecastIO(resultSet.latitude,resultSet.longitude);
               } 
            }else{
                printError({message: "Error with GEO API"+http.STATUS_CODES[response.statusCode]})
            }
        });
    });

    function connectToForecastIO(latitude,longitude){
        var forecastRequest = https.get(createForecastRequest(latitude,longitude),function(response){
           // console.log(createForecastRequest(latitude,longitude));
            var body = "";
            var status = response.statusCode;
            //read the data
             response.on("data", function(chunk){
                body+=chunk;
            });
            //parse the data
            response.on("end", function(){
                try{
                    var weatherReport = JSON.parse(body);

                    resultSet.weather = weatherReport.currently.summary;
                    resultSet.humidity = weatherReport.currently.humidity;
                    resultSet.temperature = weatherReport.currently.temperature;
                    resultSet.pressure = weatherReport.currently.pressure;
                    resultSet.time = weatherReport.currently.time;
                }catch(error){
                    printError(error.message);
                }finally{
                   console.log(resultSet);
                   // return resultSet;
                }
            });
        });    
    }
}

//define the name of the outer module.
module.exports.get = get;
```

Comment: Put the calls in the appropriate places. If you don't show us your code, we of course can't tell you which these are.

Comment: We need to know more to help you

Comment: It sounds like you could use promises or async.series, but we'd need to see your code

Comment: I agree with Bergi and james_womack 7 - You need to share your code if you want to be helped. Use https://jsfiddle.net/ to put your code in, and update your question.

Comment: there, just added the code, sorry I didn't put it the first time. @Bergi

Comment: OK, thanks. And what is the exact problem you are experiencing? You are calling `connectToForecastIO` only when the google api request succeeds with a 200 status and the response ends, so I'm having a hard time believing it's "skipped". What does not work, what results are you getting, are there any errors?

Comment: Right now it doesn't skip it because I included the call to the second API in the finally block of the first, which forces the first block of code to execute before the second API is called. However it feels forced, and I thought there was a better way of doing this. @Bergi

Comment: Well it shouldn't go in the `finally` block because you probably don't want to call it in case of an exception, but yes, that's where the callback has to go. Of course you might want to pass a generic `callback` as a parameter to  `get` instead of always calling `connectToForeCastIO`, but that's another issue.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution to your question is use of [promise](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html). They are easy to implement and prevent callback hell!!

Comment: I am new to nodes, I don't even know what a callback is, I wouldn't mind to use a callback here if I knew what it is.

Comment: Have a look at this [article](http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/nodejs-for-beginners-callbacks/4), it will give you a fair knowledge of callbacks, then read about **promise**, you will understand where you are going wrong.

Comment: @CarlosLuis: A callback is when you pass a function as an argument then call that function. In the following example, `b` is  a function: `function a (b) { b() // call b back}`. This allows you to run code when async process completes by passing that code as a function into the function that needs to do something async. It's like how `https.get()` work. You can implement something similar yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and tanks for the resource link as well. Just what I needed to take my learning to the next level.